# iphone app navigation bar multiple items

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

how can I have a back button and another button both on the left side of the nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you also need the title?  If not, you can simply place the button in the center area.  Otherwise, if you also need the title, you will need to create a UIView with a label and a button in it and set that as the center view.  You will have to set the label's text manually if the title of the view ever changes.

Or, if you don't care too much about the back button, you can create a button that looks like the back button and put your other button next to it in a parent view that you use as the left view.  You would have to manually handle going back when pressing the back button, and unless you got an image that looks like the back button, your button would not have the arrow shape.